# Seperate Numeric Whole,Decimal and/or Fraction from start of string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am trying to separate the amounts from their respective measurements for a list of recipes. This is so I can adjust amounts based on the number of serve's needed. I have the calculations working but still trying to edit the string to use in the math in the JavaScript.

Here is a list of possible values with the value I actually need in first bracket. But I also need to keep the measurement shown in second bracket.

- 1g (1) (g)
- 1 g (1) (g)
- 1/2cup (0.5) (cup)
- 1/2 cup (0.5) (cup)
- 1 1/2cup (1.5) (cup)
- 1 1/2 cup (1.5) (cup)
- 2.5g (2.5) (g)

The problem I have is the amount and measurement are in the same DB field and I cannot separate them in the back end without breaking allot of the original code. Also, any updates to the code by its author will mean I have to recode it. So any help on getting the right values would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you put your current javascript. Also what do you mean by ' any updates to the code by its author will mean I have to recode it '

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions:

```js
var input = [
  '1g (1) (g)',
  '1 g (1) (g)',
  '1/2cup (0.5) (cup)',
  '1/2 cup (0.5) (cup)',
  '1 1/2cup (1.5) (cup)',
  '1 1/2 cup (1.5) (cup)',
  '2.5g (2.5) (g)'];
function extract(item) {
  return item.match(/\(([^\)]+)\) \(([^\)]+)\)/).slice(1);
}
var output = input.map(extract);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Not sure what that's suppose to be doing, but tested as is and nothing shows up.

Comment: Also not sure you understand what I am doing. you have put exactly what I have typed as samples into the code.

The brackets are the 2 variables I expect to get out of it.

So, if I have 1/2cup as the value, run it thru the script I should get var1=0.5 var2=cup

The multiples are the majority of the different variations of the initial value I may get.

Oh, and just noticed you have the values in there as an array, This would not happen, its one at a time.

Comment: @ShaunWilliams I put them in an array just for testing, if you want to have them in var1 and var2 just use `var array = extract('2.5g (2.5) (g)'); var1=array[0]; var2=array[1];`